# Why does neo4j's GraphDatabaseService.index() throw exception if called outside of transaction?

Tags: scala, neo4j

I'm very new to Neo4j. I'm using version `2.0.0-M05`.

Why does `GraphDatabaseService.index()` throw exception if it's called outside of transaction ? Can I make it work without transaction ?

Here is my sample code

```
val graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().
  newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("test_db").
  setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_keys_indexable, "nodeProp1,nodeProp2").
  setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.relationship_keys_indexable, "relProp1,relProp2").
  setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_auto_indexing, "true").
  setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.relationship_auto_indexing, "true").
  newGraphDatabase()

val userIndex = graphDb.index().forNodes("user")
```

Causes following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.AbstractTransactionManager.assertInTransaction(AbstractTransactionManager.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.IndexManagerImpl.assertInTransaction(IndexManagerImpl.java:465)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.IndexManagerImpl.forNodes(IndexManagerImpl.java:300)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.IndexManagerImpl.forNodes(IndexManagerImpl.java:293)
    at Test$.main(Test.scala:77)
    at Test.main(Test.scala)
```

PS. It doesn't happen in `1.9.RC1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's by design.

`Previously it was considered good practice to wrap read operations inside a transaction. The 2.0.0-M04 release makes this recommendation mandatory. Any attempt to execute operations on the database outside of a transaction will now throw a NotInTransactionException. Enforcing this idiom allows Neo4j to reclaim resources much more efficiently leading to a database that will handle much more load. Cypher and the REST-API open their own transactions, so this will only affect users of the embedded Java-API.`